# Downcounter in moderncv

Tags: macros, counters, moderncv

I use my counter in `moderncv.cls` as

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\newcommand{\NbOfJournalPub}{10}
\newcounter{MyCounter}
\setcounter{MyCounter}{-1}
\newcommand*{\myJlistitem}{\stepcounter{MyCounter}[J\the\numexpr\NbOfJournalPub-\value{MyCounter}\relax]\,}

\begin{document}

\cvitem{\myJlistitem}{Journal Name, author}
\cvitem{\myJlistitem}{Journal Name, author}
\cvitem{\myJlistitem}{Journal Name, author}

\end{document}
```

I get

> [J10] Journal Name, author
>
> [J9] Journal Name, author
>
> [J8] Journal Name, author

However, I want to define `\NbOfJournalPub` that takes the value automatically.

Comment: Have a look at the https://ctan.org/pkg/revnum package. If this does not help, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @samcarter I have revised with mwe.

Comment: @Mithun: The example you posted doesn't compile. Please provide something that one can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `totcount`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{totcount}
\moderncvstyle{casual}

\newcommand{\NbOfJournalPub}{10}
\newtotcounter{MyCounter}

\newcommand*{\myJlistitem}{%
  \stepcounter{MyCounter}%
  [J\the\numexpr1+\totvalue{MyCounter}-\value{MyCounter}\relax]%
}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\cvitem{\myJlistitem}{Journal Name, author}
\cvitem{\myJlistitem}{Journal Name, author}
\cvitem{\myJlistitem}{Journal Name, author}

\end{document}
```

[image]